# Store data in a row matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a MATLAB program like this

```
for m = 1:2

    %# Some code to calculate a matrix (Ytotale)
    %# Size of Ytotale is (1200 * 144) %%

    %#...

    Yfinal = Ytotale;

    for l = 1:1200
        i = l;

        j = retard(l,1);
        if Yfinal(i,j) == 0
            Yfinal(i,j:end) = circshift(Yfinal(i,j:end),[retard(l,2) retard(l,2)]);
            for j = retard(l,1):retard(l,1)+retard(l,2)-1
                Yfinal(i,j) = 1;
            end
        else
            Yfinal(i,j:end) = circshift(Yfinal(i,j:end),[retard(l,2) retard(l,2)]);
            for j = retard(l,1):retard(l,1)+retard(l,2)-1
                Yfinal(i,j) = 0;
            end
        end

    end

    %# ( Here i , j are index of matrix Ytotale , and l is the index 
    %# of matrix retard of size (1200 * 2) 

    for i =1:1200        
        not_char(i,1) = sum(Yfinal(i,1:144));        
        req(i,1) = sum(Ytotale(i,1:144));
    end

    final = req - not_char;    
    ve_delay = sum(Yfinal(:,1:144))';

end
```

The total process will iterate from `m = 1 to 2`  and two `Ytotale` matrix will form, hence I want to store the value of `ve_delay` and final in a row matrix for each `Ytotale` , but my code overwrites the matrix values .

please help...

Comment: which values are being overwritten? Exactly what you want and the problem you are having are not clear

Comment: @Mauvai ... Suppose for m = 1 , it will calculate Ytotale. using this Ytotale we find Yfinal and then ve_delay. Now, for m = 2; again it will calculate Ytotale, Yfinal but, the ve_delay gets over writes with the new values of ve_delay. I want to store the values of ve_delay in a row matrix.

Comment: try `final{m} = req - not_char;` and `ve_delay{m} = sum(Yfinal(:,1:144))';` . These values are now stored in a cell matrix (the curly bracket notation). You can convert the cell array into a regular array afterward.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer is adapted from the comment by macduf*

Try `final{m} = req - not_char;` and `ve_delay{m} = sum(Yfinal(:,1:144));` . These values are now stored in a cell matrix (the curly bracket notation). You can convert the cell array into a regular array afterward.